# Change default autocomplete import for VSCode in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, autocomplete, project

I am building a python project using VSCode. I have a project folder structure that looks like this:

```
Project
  -> data
  -> src
    -> classes
      -> subfolder1
        -> file1.py
        -> file2.py
      -> subfolder2
  -> unittest
```

The auto-complete for VS-Code, when I try and import `file1.py` functions into `file2.py` auto-completes the import to:

```
import classes.subfolder1.file1
```

instead of

```
import src.classes.subfolder1.file1
```

how do I change what VSCode sees as the top folder?

Comment: do your src and classes folder has `__init__.py` file? 

what about subfolder1 and subfolder2?
please provide the output of complete directory structure?
you can use tree command if you are using linux

Comment: I'm on a windows machine, and I'm using python 3.9 so I was under the impression that __init__.py files are unnecessary

Comment: do read about python packages, and add `__init__.py` in src and maybe in classes and subfolder1 also if you don't want it to be a namespace package

Comment: Why not use `import method` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, adding a `__init__.py` file under the src directory fixed the issue. Thanks to Prince Roshan for the suggestion